# uint32_t destructor return value

Tags: c++

Today I saw this code, inside a class:

```
static const uint32_t invalid_index = ~uint32_t();
```

My question is, what is the return value of a `uint32_t` destructor, and why is it useful?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's not a destructor, but a **bitwise `NOT`** operator applied to a **value-initialized** `uint32_t`.

A value initialized integral type is `0`, so you're taking the bitwise `NOT` of `0`.

Similar to:

```
uint32_t x = uint32_t();  // 32 0's in binary form
uint32_t y = ~x;          // 32 1's in binary form
```

Answer (score 8):

First of all, as many have already mentioned, the code you saw,

```
static const uint32_t invalid_index = ~uint32_t();
```

is not a destructor call but the bitwise "not" `~`, applied to the default value of the type, `uint32_t()`, i.e. `~(uint32_t(0))`.

Now to your question,

> My question is, what is the return value of a uint32_t destructor, and why is it useful?

The return type of the **pseudo-destructor** (it’s not a real destructor, just a do-nothing operation with the same notation as a destructor call) is `void`, and it’s mainly useful for generic programming where you don’t know the type.

Example:

```
uint32_t x;
x.~uint32_t();  // Silly but valid, a pseudo-destructor call.
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not a destructor, it is binary not. Here the invalid index is equal to ~uint32_t(0). Which is a 32 bit unsigned integer with all bits set. i.e., 0xffffffff.

Comment: -1 "Here the invalid index is equal to uint32_t(~0)" No, not in general. The literal is an `int`, and `int` is only guaranteed to have 16 bits.

Comment: "The literal is an int, and int is only guaranteed to have 16 bits". Isn't uint32 guaranteed to be 32 bits?

Comment: @user1507133, yes, but `0` is not a `uint32_t` it's an `int`, and so is `~0`

Comment: @user1507133 sure it is, but you only cast 16 bits to 1s.

Comment: @LokiAstari: the encoding of _signed_ integers is not specified. Unsigned integers have a simple binary encoding, which is also why their overflow is well-defined.

Comment: @LokiAstari: There's no such thing as 1's complement _unsigned_. The bits must have values 1,2,4,8, etc: only positive powers of two. The only thing unspecified is byte ordering.

Answer (score 1):

It's the bitwise **NOT** and it can be used to find the ones' complement (eg. ~1011 = 0100) or as an intermediate step when trying to find the 2s complement (eg. [~1011] + 0001 = 0101).